# как узнать сколько байтов в hex строке

Tags: python-3.x

Подскажите как узнать сколько байтов в строке записанной в hex, есть необходимость валидировать ethereum кошелек, длинна каждого кошелька равно 20 байтам но как это реализовать на python не пойму

пробовал так:

```
eth = 0xf8e1f68d15e0db4e31adaed3eb0a89c1513c6dd2
print(eth.bit_length())
156
```

что совсем не то что должно быть. Спасибо.

Comment: у вас тут мешанина типов. В заголовке вы говорите о "hex строке". В коде у вас int объект из hex literal создаётся (в Питоне str и int это совсем разные вещи). Для которого вы количество [необходимых] бит выводите. Что у вас на входе? Что вы хотите на выходе точно? К примеру: `"00"` что у вас должно возвращать? 0 или 1 или 2?

Comment: Каждые два символа [A-F][0-9] представляют один байт. Так что длину строки делите на два

Comment: на входе у меня строка полученная из формы на сайте, посоветуйте как мне лучше поступить ?? 
    print(hex(eth).__len__())
    выводит 41, даже если я разделю на 2 получится 20,5 а должно быть 20

Comment: @AlexandrVasilenko а в приведенном коде у вас НЕ строка...

Comment: eth = "0x0d18B2a0901FF0048Cc36F7a6C2297FBb05B68e6" print(hex(int(eth,16)).__len__())
выводит все равно 41

Comment: не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии к собственному вопросу. Обновите ваш вопрос вместо этого. Нажмите [edit]

Comment: приведите результат `print(ascii(eth))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
>> eth = 'f8e1f68d15e0db4e31adaed3eb0a89c1513c6dd2'
>> s = bytearray.fromhex(eth)
>> print(s)
bytearray(b'\xf8\xe1\xf6\x8d\x15\xe0\xdbN1\xad\xae\xd3\xeb\n\x89\xc1Q<m\xd2')
>> len(s)
20
```

При этом, если в строке будут невалидные hex-значения или будет нечётное число символов, то при конвертации получите ошибку. И это автоматически будет означать, что номер кошелька невалиден.

Если же ошибки не возникло и длина оказалась равна 20, то всё валидно.

Comment: тоесть мне вначале нужно обрезать 0х ???

Comment: @AlexandrVasilenko Да.

Comment: это извращённый способ `len(eth)//2` записать

Comment: @jfs Это не извращение, а просто проверка на то, что это действительно hex строка, а не произвольный текст.

Comment: @zed вопрос "сколько байтов в hex строке", а не "валидируйте ввод". Если вы хотите узнать является ли строка верным ethereum адресом, то 1- это отдельный вопрос 2- и ответ другой https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1374

Answer (score 0):

```
eth = 'f8e1f68d15e0db4e31adaed3eb0a89c1513c6dd2'
print (len(eth)/2)
```

Выводит 20

Answer (score 0):

Получилось вот так:

```
>> eth = '0xf8e1f68d15e0db4e31adaed3eb0a89c1513c6dd2'
>> eth = eth[2:]
>> s = bytearray.fromhex(eth)
>> print(s)
bytearray(b'\xf8\xe1\xf6\x8d\x15\xe0\xdbN1\xad\xae\xd3\xeb\n\x89\xc1Q<m\xd2')
>> len(s)
20
```